# Are jQuery's hide and slideUp methods equivalent?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, slidedown, slideup

Do `slideUp('slow')` and `hide('slow')` result in the same animation effects?

Example Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide('slow');
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show('slow');
  });
});


<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.

`.slideUp('slow')` animates the height and vertical padding to zero.
`.hide('slow')` also animates the width, horizontal padding, and opacity to zero.

To see the difference, paste `javascript:void($('pre').hide(4000))` in the address bar in this page.

Answer (score 4):

The animation is a little different,
- slideUp('slow') basically slides up, nothing else :)
- hide('slow') slides up and left at the same time.

In jquery API doc you have good documentation:

- [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)
- [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
        $(".job-bottom").hide();
        $(".job-top").click(function(){
            $(".job-bottom").slideUp('slow')
            $(this).next(".job-bottom").slideToggle( "slow" );
        });
    });
```