# What is the difference between JQuery's hide() and slideDown()/slideUp()?

Tags: jquery, hide, slidedown, slideup

It seems like after calling both result is the same.

Comment: you should be able to find your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290152/jquery-slideupslow-vs-hideslow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `show`/`hide` methods animates width, height and opacity, while `slideUp`/`sideDown` only animates the height.

The default duration of `show`/`hide` is zero, so if you don't specify a duartion it will show/hide the element immediately.

If you are not seeing any difference between the methods, then they are most likely not working propery with the element that you apply them to. A common reason for that is that you are testing in Internet Explorer, and the element doesn't have the layout flag. If you for example try to animate a table cell, the style changes that the animation does on the element won't apply, and you will just see that the element is shown/hidden.

Answer (score 4):

`slideDown()` and `slideUp()` animates the hiding/showing.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `hide` method will simply apply `display: none` to the selected element(s), unless a duration is provided - then it will animate. The slide methods are members of the effects queue, they will hide/show the element(s) in a sliding motion.

Answer (score 2):

`hide()` instantly hides the div.

while `slidetoggle(), slidedown() & slideup()` do the same with some animation effects. there is some sliding effects in these functions. thats the difference.

nothing else.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) simply sets the `display: none` CSS attribute **unless you specify a duration**. If you do so, it will fade out.

[`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) is always animated.

The same applies for `show()` and `slideDown()`.

Answer (score 1):

The only diffrence that exists between hide() and slideup () /slidedown() is the animation. Slide up/down will simply slide and hide will simply hide. The two methods can be used with a duration / easing option. for more information http://api.jquery.com/hide/ and
http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Answer (score 0):

hide() means it reduce the height ,width and opacity attribute value  until height=0,width=0 and opacity=0 and (padding and margin are optional if the value are not zero then it also reduce the value to zero)

slideUp() means it reduce the attribute value until zero those attribute are height,margin-top,margin-bottom,padding-top and padding-bottom

slideDown() is reverse of slideUp() it increase the value until the actual, define in our source code.