# why slideDown() is not working in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Its a simple one. But i just confused.

Here is jquery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jquery </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>welcome to jquery</h2>
<p>Jquery is invented by John Resig</p>
<button id="button">submit</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() {
$("h2").slideDown(400);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working, but `slideUp()` is working fine.

May i know why? what is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxd3rt0/ check its working

Comment: It's working I tested it.

Comment: sorry for all,, i posted wrong.. now i updated.. thanks

Comment: What does "But it is not working, but `slideUp()` is working fine." mean? If "it" refers to `slideDown` the element should be hidden at first. `$("h2").hide().slideDown(400);`

Comment: i mean, slideDown() is not working

Comment: Check now actually first you need to display none that content on page load after that it will work because if content is already showing then what it will slide down

Comment: so, if use slideDown(), then we should use display:none; right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to hide content which you want to slideDown after that it will work see below example

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jquery </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 style="display:none;">welcome to jquery</h2>
<p>Jquery is invented by John Resig</p>
<button id="button">submit</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() {
$("h2").slideDown(400);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may i know, why display:none; ? @Yogesh Sharma:

Comment: Because slidedown function work to show hidden content, first it show content if content is hide by defualt. let's think if content is already visible then what it will do?

Comment: If you want to show content and want it ti slide down then only possible solution is fisrt do it slideUp and the you can slideDown this is only way to do this

Comment: so ,, content->hide(already)->show(want to show) means, use slideDown(); and content ->show(already)->hide(want to hide) means, use slideUp(); right?

Comment: I mean if you want to apply both slideUp and slideDown then it's possible, in this case content will show by defualt then click it will hide with slideUp and then it will show again with slideDown

Comment: one more think.,that means, we use hide() or show() right.. ? Why we use slideUp() and slideDown()? Thanks..

Comment: Actually SlideUp and slide down gives animation effect

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187476/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-hide-and-slidedown-slideup post for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:Actually that `h2` is in slideDown ,so if u apply `slideDown` it does not work.you can do two ways one is make the `h2`  `display:none`
 or `hide` the he using jquery.then you can call `slideDown`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("h2").hide();
   $("button").click(function() {
     $("h2").slideDown(400);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbxd3rt0/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() {

    if($('h2').attr('style') == "display:none;")  {  
$("h2").slideDown(400);
    }else{
   $("h2").slideUp(400);     
    }
});
});
```